# mp4 in mobile Safari doesn't play, but the same webpage loaded in a UIWebView does play

Tags: ios, html5-video

I'm using a `video` tag:

```
<video width="300" height="168" poster="poster.jpg" webkit-playsinline="true">
    <source src="http://mydomain/ad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'll try to load the page in mobile Safari, but the play button is crossed out (circle with a line through it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60w9o.png). When I load the page in a UIWebView, the play button is enabled and I can play the video -- no problem.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all audio/video codecs or bit rates are supported depending on your device.  The easiest way to test a given file is compatible with the device is to drop the file directly on a web server and access it directly from mobile safari without html.  It should play automatically once you navigate directly to the media.